# ohmyfetch (Nuxt 3 $fetch) how to remove 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' from content-type header?

Tags: javascript, http, nuxtjs3, postgrest

I am trying to send a post request to PostgREST to invoke a stored procedure:

```
  const data = await $fetch('http://http-logger:3001/rpc/test_proc', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Prefer: 'params=single-object',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    },
    body: {some: 'json'}
})
```

Results in this request:

```
POST /rpc/test_proc HTTP/1.1
host: http-logger:3001
connection: keep-alive
prefer: params=single-object
accept: application/json
content-type: application/json, text/plain;charset=UTF-8
accept-language: *
sec-fetch-mode: cors
user-agent: undici
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 15


{"some":"json"}
```

I need to remove the '`text/plain;charset=UTF-8`' part from the content-type. Is this possible? Should it even be there as I have explicitly defined the content-type header?
Many thanks
Ian

Comment: dont remove it, it just lets the browser and sever know that the byte data format is of utf-8

Comment: otherwise, the possible values could be ascii, utf-16, utf-32, etc, etc\

Comment: if you want to set it to something then set it to `'Content-Type':  'application/json, text/plain;charset=UTF-16'`

Comment: I need to remove it because the PostgREST server does not accept content-type text/plain and returns a 400 status.